# Mongoose Unique is not working , assign the duplicate values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

This is my full code where i an trying to validate the data from user

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from './user.interface';
const userSchema = new Schema<User>({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'User ID must be unique'],
    unique: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'username must be unique'],
    unique: true,
    trim:true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required and must be unique'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid email format'],
  },
});
export const UserModel = model<User>('User', userSchema);
```

but here unique is not working

on the other hand my previous code below. where its working.

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import validator from 'validator'

const studentSchema = new Schema<Student>({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Student ID must be unique'],
    unique: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Student username must be unique'],
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email must be unique'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});

export const StudentModel = model<Student>('Student', studentSchema);
```

I need to validate the data. an the id , username, and the email is unique in my mongoose

Comment: You say "*but here unique is not working*"...what's not working? Is the data failing validation, is it saving data with values that already exist? If so which fields? What data are you sending? How are you saving it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying the unique constraint to an existing collection, ensure that there are no pre-existing documents violating this uniqueness constraint. You can add the below your model

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ id : 1 }, { unique: true });
```